# How to generate HTML pages with Grunt using views and layouts?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

I'm just starting to use Grunt in my projects. My typical project includes a layout file and several view files. I'd like to generate one HTML page per view file using the layout file.

For example, here is a layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- some css -->
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- some js -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and a view file:

```
<h1>Lorem</h1>
<p>Some other stuff</p>
```

The result I'm hoping to get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- some css -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <p>Some other stuff</p>

  <!-- some js -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Based on a quick Google Search, there are many plugins that say they can generate HTML, such as `grunt-html-build` and `grunt-generator`. I took a closer look at `grunt-html-build`, but it does not seem to fit my needs. So which Grunt plugin should I use so that I can get the results I want?

Comment: I like to use Jade. It has a grunt plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a simple series of HTML partials and [Grunt Concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) to piece them together.

Your Gruntfile would look like this:

```
concat:
  partials:
    options:
      process: true
    files:
      # destination as key, sources as value
      "dist/index.html": ["partials/_header.html", "partials/_home-page.html", "partials/_footer.html"]
```

**EDIT:**

I've moved to using [Assemble](http://assemble.io) for this task. Assemble also lets you use Handlebars and a data source to generate your HTML.

Comment: This could work, but I ended up using assemble, because it has many other useful features. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem, I was going to mention assemble but figured I'd start with the "lighter" solution first. You can also use assemble with concat to do some cool things with YAML + Handlebars.

Comment: Assemble is a more satisfying answer (not only to me, but to @akasfei), so either this answer should be updated or a new answer should be created.

Answer (score 0):

My project do that !

Light version https://github.com/thierryc/grunt-handlebars-layouts

This task has two required properties, `src` and `dest`. `src` is the path to your source file and `dest` is the file this task will write to (relative to the grunt.js file). If this file already exists **it will be overwritten**.

```
  files: {
    'dest.html': 'src.html'
  },
```

An example configuration looks like this:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    handlebarslayouts: {
      home: {
        files: {
          'dist/home.html': 'src/home.html'
        },
        options: {
          partials: [
            'src/partials/*.hbs',
            'src/layout.html'
          ],
          modules: [
            'src/helpers/helpers-*.js'
          ],
          basePath: 'src/',
          context: {
            title: 'Layout Test',
            items: [
              'apple',
              'orange',
              'banana'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['handlebarslayouts']);
```

```

Comment: You should really disclose that it's your project in your answer.